# Jenkins job in slave using maven - Maven home doesn't exist

Tags: maven, jenkins, master-slave

I am experiencing an issue running Jenkins job using slaves.

The job is a Maven job, that updates code from svn and then build and run tests, this project runs well in both master and slave as a standalone project.

The issue is when Master launch this project in the slave, in that case I see:

```
...
Svn Update OK
Error: Maven Home c:\maven doesn't exist
```

Both servers have maven on that dir, and both servers are able to run the build without master/slave setup.

Comment: check for spaces somewhere in the path C:\maven ... ??

Comment: Is Jenkins running as a slave service on your slave machine? Does it have correct access/permissions to the C:\maven folder?

Comment: I could solve the problem, unfortunately It was a distraction I made, I ran the slave start command on another vm with similar ip address (One ended with 100 and the other with 110) Yes... shame on me!

Answer (score 6):

Finally,I solve this problem. 
The reason of "Error: Maven Home c:\maven doesn´t exist" is that your slave node use the master`s maven setting . If the slave want to use its own setting , it has to override that.
Override the settings as follows:
**System Management**  ->  **Node Management** -> your slave setting -> **Node Properties** -> check the *Tools Locations* -> **Add** , then set the slave maven option,*alias* select "maven",*directory* write with the slave maven directory.
you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke your top-level maven targets and set the goals and path to pom, for instance:
goals: clean install
Pom: /home/merbel/sth/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solve this issue, it was very simple just we need to check the global configuration that in maven part we have given correct path or not as a maven home.

for example: in global tools configuration..>come down in maven home part

maven Name: M2_HOME
MAVEN_HOME: /opt/maven

like this we need to give correct path where maven was untar so after checking this try once.....

in most cases it works succesfully.....